# Is it possible to publish for iOS16 with a MacBook Pro from 2015?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I want to release my app for both iOS15 and 16. The problem is that Xcode 14 is only supported with macOS13 and my 2015 MBP cannot run anything higher than macOS12. Is it still possible to release for both iOS16?
Also, suppose I have Xcode 14, if I target iOS 15.2, will it release it for iOS15.2 and up or just iOS 15.2? If not, how can I release for two platforms at the same time?

Comment: You need to use XCode 14 to release App on AppStore. When you specify the deployment target to iOS 15.2 , that means your app will be able to run on device running iOS 15.2 , 16, 17, … It is the minimum iOS version required by your app.

Comment: Xcode 14.2 runs on macOS 12. You can download it from [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com).